# Create Javascript like Mustache Helpers (Lambda) functions in ruby

Tags: ruby, mustache

I was unable to find any documentation or example to create Mustache Lambda which gives access to the current context and create mustache js like lambda helpers.

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the Mustache library code, I found out that one can access the current context using `context.current` and use it to recursively call `render` method.
Here is how to achieve it. Hope it will help others.

```
class MustacheTemplateHelper < Mustache
self.raise_on_context_miss = true

def context
    super
end

def self.render(expression, replacementContext = {})
    new.render(expression, replacementContext)
end

def render(expression, replacementContext = {})
    replacementContext = replacementContext.merge(self.class.helperMethod(context))
    super
end

def self.helperMethod(context)
    return lambdaMethods = Hash[
        "ToYaml" => lambda do | expression |
               # this statement renders the string part between ToYaml tags 
                renderedString = render(expression, context.current)   # context.current contains current context
                startIndentationSize = renderedString[/\A */].size
                return JSON.parse(renderedString.gsub('=>', ':').gsub(":nil,", ":null,"))
                    .to_yaml().delete_prefix("---\n").indent(startIndentationSize)
            end
    ]
end
```

---

Template:

```
{{#configs}}
- name: {{{name}}}
  inputs:
    {{#ToYaml}}
    {{{parameters}}}
    {{/ToYaml}}
{{/configs}}
```

---

Sample Config:

```
{"configs"=>[{"name"=>"Test1", "parameters"=>{"param1"=> "demo1", "param2"=>"demo2"}}, 
                {"name"=>"Test2", "parameters"=>{"param3"=> "demo3", "param4"=>"demo4"}}]}
```